# Dependency logging with application insights does not log responses

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, restsharp

We have set up application insights with our ASP.NET Core 6 application which uses application insights for logging. We use a RestSharp based HTTP client for executing HTTP requests which works fine.

When trying to debug calls made through the RestSharp library, I am not seeing any response bodies being logged, only the statuscode, while the requests are being (kind of) logged:

[image: App Insights logging]

```json
{
  "name": "AppDependencies",
  "time": "2023-02-02T06:05:04.6268266Z",
  "tags": {
    "ai.application.ver": "1.0.0.0",
    "ai.cloud.roleInstance": "MY_NICE_PC",
    "ai.user.id": "ltK4V",
    "ai.operation.id": "11bf52695a8d8ea19f1cb7573f2b195b",
    "ai.operation.parentId": "324234234234",
    "ai.operation.name": "POST to/somewhere [v]",
    "ai.location.ip": "::1",
    "ai.internal.sdkVersion": "rdddsc:2.21.0-429",
    "ai.internal.nodeName": "MY_NICE_PC"
  },
  "data": {
    "baseType": "RemoteDependencyData",
    "baseData": {
      "ver": 2,
      "name": "POST /none/of-your/business",
      "id": "bfa554335eefae0b",
      "data": "https://none.of.your.business/my-nice-api-0/my=1&nice&=2&querystring=3",
      "duration": "00:00:04.8666247",
      "resultCode": "422",
      "success": false,
      "type": "Http",
      "target": "none.of.your.business",
      "properties": {
        "DeveloperMode": "true",
        "AspNetCoreEnvironment": "localdev",
        "_MS.ProcessedByMetricExtractors": "(Name:'Dependencies', Ver:'1.1')"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We are using ASP.NET Core 6.0 with the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` version 2.2.21 and the following DI setup:

```cs
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(configure =>
            {
                configure.ConnectionString = "MySecretConnectionString";
                configure.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false;
            });
```

--- Edit:
I also made an implementation of the `ITelemetryInitializer` to capture all telemetry for all instances of `DependencyTelemetry`:

```cs
public class DependencyTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            // SKIP for now
            if (telemetry is DependencyTelemetry dependencyTelemetry)
            {

            }
            
        }
    }
```

This showed me that for *every dependency call* only the request is being captured, but the response is *not*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to fix this, the issue with not being able to log large response bodies had to to with treading, I fixed by not waiting for the task to complete, this works for me:

```cs
 private static async Task TryUpdateTelemetryWithResponseBody(DependencyTelemetry dependencyTelemetry, HttpResponseMessage response)
        {
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await response.Content.LoadIntoBufferAsync();
                var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

                using var reader = new StreamReader(
                  stream,
                  Encoding.UTF8,
                  detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: false,
                  bufferSize: 8192, leaveOpen: true);

                var responseBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                dependencyTelemetry.Properties.Add("responseBody", responseBody);
                dependencyTelemetry.Success = true;
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

That is by design, the dependency call basically logs the outgoing call, as that is what application insights has access to. It logs the duration, and also the response code (422 in your example.) I am also not sure what kind of information you would expect to see from the response.

If you want to get access to the response you can do so in a [TelemetryInitializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#addmodify-properties-itelemetryinitializer):

```cs
public class CustomInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        if (telemetry is DependencyTelemetry dt
                && dt.Type.Equals("http", System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                && dt.TryGetHttpResponseOperationDetail(out var response))
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

You can then access the headers etc. Technically you can access the response content but since it is a stream by default it can only be read. So reading the full response content can't be done here withouth breaking the application afaik.

Also, even if you could, you should be carefull regarding logging the request and response playload. The size might be large, and Application Insights is not designed for that kind of log data. You might also hit [the limits to the lenght of the custom properties](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/includes/application-insights-limits.md) and the logged payload will be cut off.

Comment: I want to log the response body/payload. If application insights can log the response code, which is in the same object (`HttpResponseMessage`), why can't it log the response body? It does it for Request Telemetry.

Comment: I don't think Application Insights logs request body either. Response body is trickier to operate with. For instance, it is a stream and can be read only once. Response code as a part of an object which is always available and can be read multiple times.

Comment: If you need to track response body then you might need to read it yourself and then add it as a custom dimension.

Comment: From where can I read the response body from a dependency call? @ZakiMa

Comment: @PeterBons, your answer causes side effects since the stream already has been read the next read action (the real one) causes an exception.

Comment: @WilkovanderVeen, your application is making this network call and response body can be read only once. It means that in your application where this response code is read you can also put it as a custom dimension. Note, that if you're using 3rd party libraries and don't interact with network request directly you most likely will not be able to do it.

Comment: @PeterBons, I think you should revert your answer to your first iteration. The current iteration (reading body in telemetry initializer) recommends a code which will break applications.

Comment: @ZakiMa I did add a warning, but I have updated the answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following, since it is needed to buffer the response, so that it can be read again, I have added the `LoadIntoBufferAsync`. Also this seems be available as `Async` only.

```cs
 public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
 {
       if (telemetry is DependencyTelemetry dependencyTelemetry && 
             dependencyTelemetry.Type.Equals(DEPENDENCYTELEMETRY_TYPE_HTTP, 
             StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                            && dependencyTelemetry.TryGetHttpResponseOperationDetail(out var response))
            {
                var task = Task.Run(async () => await response.Content.LoadIntoBufferAsync());
                task. Wait();

                var stream = response.Content.ReadAsStream();

                using var reader = new StreamReader(
                   stream,
                   Encoding.UTF8,
                   detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: false,
                   bufferSize: 512, leaveOpen: true);

                var responseBody = reader.ReadToEnd();

                dependencyTelemetry.Properties.Add("responseBody", responseBody);
            }
        }
```

> This only seems to be working with very small stream sizes (response sizes) less than 1K. I

Comment: Nice, well at least I could give a hint in the right direction regarding the `TryGetHttpResponseOperationDetail`

Comment: But still, my opinion is that storing the response or request content using App Insights is not what it is designed for and you may hit limits on large bodies

Comment: @PeterBons I agree with you on the issue of large bodies sizes. I am also going to discuss this.

Comment: @PeterBons in fact, it does not work correctly because of large body sizes.

Comment: What you could do is write the body to a blob and store a reference to that blob in the telemetry. This makes it harder to query maybe but at least you have all the data when needed. Not sure about the performance though, you will need to think that out by using some kind of background work. On a large volume of requests you do not want to pay a large performance penalty.

Comment: @PeterBons that is a very neat solution. I will ask if they want to use some kind of storage for that.